# What are the differences between Dreamweaver_14_LS20.dmg and Dreamweaver_13_LS20.dmg?

Tags: macos, dmg, adobe, versions

I find that there are two versions of Dreamweaver CC for Mac OSX, one is Dreamweaver_14_LS20 and another is Dreamweaver_13_LS20. Can anyone tell me what is the exactly differences between these two versions.

By the way, where can I download the full installer of Adobe Software on the official web site? I only find the `CreativeCloudInstall` which will download the others later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dreamweaver CC came in two major versions: the initial CC release (v13) and the CC 2014 release (v14). From the file names, you can infer which is which.

As for a "full installer", there is no such animal now. You install CC apps individually through the Creative Cloud Manager which downloads and installs the selected app(s).

Comment: Is there any differences between v13 and v14?

Comment: Honestly I haven't used either of them to offer an opinion.

Comment: After the tries of the two version, It is exactly two different versions, and there are no relationships between these versions. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The number refers to the **version number of Dreamweaver**. For a changelog, see:

- http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/whats-new.html